# Embedded binary target's code sign settings match the parent app's

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting this error when compile adhoc build for submitting or testing.

**error**: Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app. Verify the embedded binary target's code sign settings match the parent app's.

```
    Embedded Binary Signing Certificate:    - (Ad Hoc Code Signed)
    Parent App Signing Certificate:     iPhone Distribution:------. (---------)
```

Can Anyone provide solutions for me?

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: its being coming on when i generate archieve